# cmake gui windows environment variables path

Tags: windows, cmake, environment-variables

I'm trying to point source and destination folders via Environment Variables.

```
%SRC_DIR%/src     --not working
$(SRC_DIR)/src    --not working
Env{SRC_DIR}/src  --not working
```

I tried every weird syntax and searched Google. The variable `SRC_DIR` is set and working through Explorer (`%SRC_DIR%/src`).

So how to do this?
What syntax should I use?

Comment: Are we talking about the CMake GUI or just the CMakeLists.txt? In the latter case, use $ENV{SRC_DIR}.

Comment: Im talking about CMAKE GUI source and destination textboxes

Comment: I was afraid you would say that. I would expect %SRC_DIR% to work, but see that you already tried it. Sorry.

Comment: Uhm. Why are you setting paths as env vars? If you except that CMake will look at them after configuration, i doubt it would work. So just pass actual values.

Comment: GUI + variables is a strange mix.  The GUI is inherently for manually-input items.  So just manually input the right directory.  If you're trying to script something, then either script it into CMake directly, or expand the value outside CMake and put it into the cache file.  The GUI should pick it up from there.

Comment: GUI + variables is a fine mix. It's a real pity the CMake GUI doesn't support this. I wonder if it's the same on Linux.